# what does “curriculum” means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

- a motivational letter
- a curriculum

Guys, I got an e-mail and it said in it, but it doesn't say "vitae" at the end, does that mean they still want the resume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably provide the full text you've been sent for context. But if the email is about employment or some other kind of application you have made where you would be expected to provide evidence of your qualifications or achievements, it would be a reasonable guess that they mean a *curriculum vitae*, known in some English dialects as a *résumé*.

A 'curriculum' is a collection of studies, usually related. For example, a 'school curriculum' would be the planned programme of subjects and topics discussed during a period of schooling.

I'm not a Latin expert, but *vitae* means 'life', so a *curriculum vitae* is literally your life's 'course' - a summary of your life's education, work, and other relevant experience.

Comment: Very often in the UK, a _curriculum vitae_ (or _curriculum vitæ_) is just called a 'CV', and many people who create and submit them do not know what the initials stand for.